# No response from v.performClick()

Tags: java, android, android-view, onclicklistener

Does any scenario leads to no response from `v.performClick()`.

```
public class AnalyzeCompleteListener implements Listner {

    public void onEvent(ImageView v) {
         Log.d("MyTest", "Test A " + v);
         boolean is_click = v.performClick();
         Log.d("MyTest", "Test B" + is_click);
    }

}
```

In another class:

```
private android.view.View.OnClickListener clicklistener = new android.view.View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Log.d("MyTest", "Execute clicklistener");
    }
}
ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
view.setOnClickListener(clicklistener);
```

According to the return value `performClick()`, this API returns `true` if there was an assigned `OnClickListener` that was called, `false` otherwise is returned.  However, I only see the debug message "Test A android.widget.ImageView@417bf378".  No "Test B" and no "Execute..." presents.

Does any scenario leads to no response from `v.performClick()`.

Comment: I tried to move v.performClick() to the following line of view.setOnClickListener(clicklistener), and the listener is called.  That means the listener indeed bind to the view, but why there is no response from the AnalyzeCompleteListener?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in two different classes. In one class you set the click listener and in another you performclick. These two classes are not related to each other and the first class is not aware of the imageview of second class.

Comment: The performClick() is invoked on the ImageView which is new on another class.  There is only one view instance in my code.  Besides, the performClick() should return in any way, isn't it?